# Which properties are stable under convergence in distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

I'm currently looking at convergence in distribution (i.e. weak convergence) of random variables. A question is bothering me since quite a while and I hope I could express it properly: Given weak convergence of a sequence $X_n\Rightarrow X$ to some random variable $X$I want to know which properties of the sequence $X_n$ are "herited" by the limit.

What came to my mind fist, is the nice Portmanteaus Theorem, stating that for example

$X_n\Rightarrow X$ iff $\liminf_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}[X_n\in O]\geq\mathbb{P}[X\in O]$.

Thus a property of the sequence like $X_n\notin(0,1)$ (by that I mean $\mathbb{P}[X_n\in(0,1)]=0$ for all $n$) is still true in the limit! Why? Well, in the above example we have $0=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}[X_n\in(0,1)]\geq\mathbb{P}[X\in(0,1)]\geq0$, thus $\mathbb{P}[X\in(0,1)]=0$. If we would take the set $[0,1)$ instead, this is not true anymore as the stupid counterexample $X_n=-\frac{1}{n}$ shows.

Now to my actual question: Are there any other results, apart from Portmanteaus Theorem, which allow for similar arguments? Which properties are inherited? Only "open" and "closed" ones?

Comment: One can show that the weak convergence is equivalent to $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}[X_n \in B] = \mathbb{P}[X \in B]$$ for any Borel set $B$ such that $\mathbb{P}[X \in \partial B]=0.$

Comment: Thank's for your answer saz and sry for not mentioning this in my post, but this result still counts as a part of Portmanteau Theorem for me ;)

Comment: Yes, certainly, but I wasn't sure whether you are aware of this equivalent formulation.